# Setting up the legend for a scatterplot in Python

Tags: python, legend, xlrd

I have imported some data from an excel file onto Python and I wanted to do a scatterplot. The problem I'm having is with the legend. I include the code below:

```
data_2 = xlrd.open_workbook('/Users/.../.../Book1.xlsx')
sheet = data_2.sheet_by_index(0)
sheet.cell_value(0,0)
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (11,8), facecolor='white', edgecolor='black')
plt.xlabel('some x label')
plt.ylabel('some y label')
plt.xticks(np.arange(0.0, 30, 1.0))
plt.yticks(np.arange(-9.50, 1.0, 0.50))
plt.axhline(y=0.0, color='grey', linestyle=':')
plt.margins(0.01)
plt.savefig('plot.png')

for i in range(1, sheet.nrows):
    xval = sheet.cell_value(i,0)
    for j in range(1, sheet.ncols):
        yval = sheet.cell_value(i,j)
        plt.scatter(xval,yval, label = 'i = {}'.format(j))
plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5)) #the legend will appear on the right of the figure
```

While the scatterplot is fine, the legend entries repeat 31 times (31 being the number of columns in the dataset).  I cannot figure out what is causing the problem. I have tried different placement of the line `plt.legend(..)` but unsuccessfully. I have tried building the legend from scratch but extracting the colours of the dots from the plot was hard! How can I modify the code to output the legend with `sheet.ncols` - 1(The first column in the dataset are the xaxis values) entries only on the right?

If it helps, this is the graph I get when I use Excel to plot the data (but I don't want to use Excel for plots)
[image]

I want the code to reproduce such a plot in python. Note the legend placement is at the bottom but it would be better to have it on the right of the figure

Comment: You'll get a legend entry for each labeled `Line` object in the plot (each time you call `plt.scatter(xval,yval, label = 'i = {}'.format(j))` ). Is that what you want?

Comment: @JoshuaF No. I want a legend with (sheet.ncols -1) entries, with each entry being of form " i = column_number ". The same legend applies for each scatterplot generated when running `plt.scatter(xval,yval, label = 'i = {}'.format(j))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try only labeling one row's worth of entries, with something like `plt.scatter(xval,yval, label = 'i = {}'.format(j) if i==1 else None)`. Matplotlib will automatically create a legend entry for each labeled object on the plot regardless of the label's content.

Answer (score 0):

```
import xlrd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data_2 = xlrd.open_workbook(".\Book1.xls")
sheet = data_2.sheet_by_index(0)
sheet.cell_value(0,0)
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (11,8), facecolor="white", edgecolor="black")
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.xticks(np.arange(0.0, 30, 1.0))
plt.yticks(np.arange(-9.50, 1.0, 0.50))
plt.axhline(y=0.0, color="grey", linestyle=":")
plt.margins(0.01)

for i in range(1, sheet.nrows):
    xval = sheet.cell_value(i, 0)
    for j in range(1, sheet.ncols):
        yval = sheet.cell_value(i, j)
        plt.scatter(xval, yval, label = "i={}".format(j))
plt.legend(loc="center left", bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))

plt.savefig("plot.png")
```

I'm not sure what you did wrong, because I basically used your code, only shifting the `for` loop up so the plot didn't come up empty, but didn't get the error you got.

[image: Diagram with only one legend]

The dataset is simple:

```
0, -2, -0.5, 1, 0, -1.5
1, -4, -2, -3, 1, 0.7
2, 1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.88, 1
```

Comment: I can't see if you have uploaded any picture, but when i run the code, I have this nasty legend repeating

Comment: Yeah, but you see, there's 'i = 1, i = 2, i = 3, i = 4, i =5" twice. In the dataset that I have, for each row entry, I have 31 column entries labelled "i = column_number". so basically, If I label the columns as Y1, Y2,..., Y31, and the xaxis values as X, I am doing a scatterplot for (X,Y1), (X,Y2), ...(X, Y31).  The same legend applies for each scatterplot.

Comment: Ah, that's the repetition you meant. For some reason I had thought that the box containing the legend appeared 31 times... We'll need to look at that code again, then.